# How do I run gdb on .net unit tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, gdb

I have some code which does native interop and is having a segfault when running unit tests with dotnet test.

If I call the test code without 'dotnet test' then it doesn't segfault.

I need to be able to run gdb to debug the segfault but running gdb on 'dotnet test' doesn't work, it seems that it launches another process to do the tests. This means the segfault happens on a process that gdb isn't attached to.
For example the following command doesn't result in gdb being able to catch the segfault.

> gdb --args dotnet test

How can I use gdb to debug native c# interop in my .net unit tests.

(the tests actually use SpecFlow which uses nunit)

Comment: Related? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13058

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Visual Studio or VS Code?

Comment: Linux with VS Code, although I run gdb from the command line so the IDE is irrelevant.